# Get client's IP Address in common c# Class Library for WebAPI and WebApplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, class-library

My business layer is common for WebApi and WebApplication. Need to track the client's IP address for each action. Searched on web and tried this but on development but I think this is for Server . I am getting server's ip address:

```
var host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
string ipAddress = host.AddressList[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this extension method:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
    {
        public static string GetIpAddress(this HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                return httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

older .Net version example:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets the IP address for the current request, returns 0.0.0.0 if HttpsContext does not exist.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetIpAddress()
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            var ipAddress = String.Empty;

            if (context != null)
            {
                ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress))
                {
                    ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                }
                else
                {
                    var ipAddresses = ipAddress.Split(new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (ipAddresses.Length > 0)
                    {
                        ipAddress = ipAddresses[0];
                    }
                }

                ipAddress = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress) ? context.Request.UserHostName : ipAddress;
            }
            return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress) ? "0.0.0.0" : ipAddress;
        }
```

Comment: The project is a Class Library (.NET Framework) .. I added reference to system.web but getting this error - HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Connection' and no extension method 'Connection' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I guess it depends on the .version of .net you are using, I have added another method that I use in older .net versions.

Comment: Original development app is getting 0.0.0.0 .. that means HttpContext.Current is null .. the method is calling through Hangfire job .what should I do

Comment: Ah ok, Hangfire will be creating threads outside of the HttpContext, so you will not have access to that info... I don't know what you app is doing, but I suspect that a user action will be triggering something that Hangfire will do later, so you will need to get the IP at that point and save or and possibly pass that as a parameter when queuing the Hangfire call.